# A referential integrity constraint violation occurred mvc4

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

i have this classes :

```
Public Class Customer
      Public Property CustomerID As Integer
      Public Property CustomerName As String
      Public Property OrdersList As ICollection(Of Order)
End Class

Public Class Order
          Public Property OrderID As Integer
          Public Property CustomerID As Integer
          Public Property OrderTotal As Decimal
          Public Property OrderDetails As ICollection(Of OrderDetail)
          Public Property OrderCustomer As Customer
End Class

Public Class OrderDetail

    Public Property OrderDetailID As Integer
    Public Property OrderID As Integer
    Public Property ProductID As Integer
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Property Quantity As Decimal
    Public Property LineTotal As Decimal

    Public Property OrderDetailOrder As Order
    Public Property OrderDetailProduct As Product

End Class

Public Class Product
    Public Property ProductID As Integer
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property ProductPrice As Decimal
    Public Property OrderDetails As ICollection(Of OrderDetail)
End Class
```

and this is the PUT Method

```
Function PutOrder(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal order As Order) As HttpResponseMessage
        If ModelState.IsValid And id = order.OrderID Then
            db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified
            Try
                db.SaveChanges()
            Catch ex As DbUpdateConcurrencyException
                 Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            End Try
            Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        Else
            Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
End Function
```

but when execute :**db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified**
i have this error

A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

thank u all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that

- either `order.CustomerID != order.OrderCustomer.CustomerID`
- or `OrderDetail.OrderID != OrderDetail.OrderDetailOrder.OrderID` for at least one of the OrderDetails
- or `OrderDetail.ProductID != OrderDetail.OrderDetailProduct.ProductID` for at least one of the OrderDetails

You must ensure that those values are equal before you attach the `order` to the context.

Comment: always my order didn't come  with those property like: order.OrderCustomer= nothing , OrderDetail.OrderDetailProduct= nothing is that right?

Comment: @Senator: What about the collections, for example `order.OrderDetails`? If the `OrderDetails` in this collection don't have the correct `OrderID` set, you might get this exception as well, but I am not sure.

Comment: i try this : `For Each objOrderDetails In order.OrderDetails
                    objOrderDetails.OrderID = order.OrderID
                Next

                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified`   but i have this error : **An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.** ,sorry for bad formatting

Comment: @Senator: It looks that your loop has removed the old error and you get another one that was hidden by the first error. Is the `OrderDetail.OrderDetailOrder` navigation property **not** `Nothing` and do they all refer to the `order` instance that enters the `PutOrder` method?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the solution

```
    Dim x = db.Orders.Include(Function(a) a.OrderDetails).Include(Function(o) o.OrderCustomer).FirstOrDefault
    db.Entry(x).CurrentValues.SetValues(order)
```

thank u @Slauma ,your tips is helpfull